# Java when use while loop the rest of the code doesn't run

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Sorry i didn't say it correct. I want the while loop because the text has to update every time. So if the text document has changed, the text also has to change.

I have made a little java program that reads a text document and prints it on the screen. Till now you need to press a button to refresh the text, when i want to do it with a while loop, then the code is doesn't run correctly.

Log.java:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;



public class Log extends JFrame {

    String file1;
    JButton but;
    JTextArea textArea;
    static String username=System.getProperty("user.name");
    public static void  main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException{
    Log b = new Log();
    b.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    b.setSize(700,900);
    b.setVisible(true);
}

public Log() throws InterruptedException, IOException{
    super("Text File Reader");

    textArea = new JTextArea(50, 60);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea); 
    textArea.setEditable(true);
    add(scrollPane);

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    but=new JButton("Reload");
    add(but);

    thehandeler handeler= new thehandeler();

    but.addActionListener(handeler);

     // Can't use a while loop :(
     //while(true){
     file1= new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\"+username+"\\Desktop\\mc Server 1.8.7\\logs\\latest.log")));
     textArea.append(file1);
     //}
}

private class thehandeler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource()==but){
            try {
                file1= new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\"+username+"\\Desktop\\mc Server 1.8.7\\logs\\latest.log")));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            textArea.setText(file1);
        }
        }   
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: plz share stack trace for error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting a question, please take a moment to consider how much of your code is actually relevant, and post a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem. Your question currently contains nearly 100 lines of code, but doesn't explain what "doesn't run correctly" actually means. You should also put effort into formatting your code so that it's easy to read.

Comment: Pretty sure your problem is here: while(true)

Comment: `while loop` with a `true` `boolean` condition will continue to run endlessly unless you have specified a conditional statement.

Comment: Agree with @jrahhali. The intention of a loop is to continue iterating until something is satisfied and then kill the loop. while(true) or while(1) are expensive and bad practice. Consider always having some condition to kill the loop or else it can lock up your machine/ide.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading all file in a row with `Files.readAllBytes`, actually *you don't need a `while` loop and it does not make sense*.

Also, `while(true)` will create an infinite loop that you need to break somewhere. If you want to read with a while loop use a `BufferedReader` and read each line of the file by `readLine()` method. Something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\"+username+"\\Desktop\\mc Server 1.8.7\\logs\\latest.log"));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    String everything = sb.toString();
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

If you want to use `while(true)` use `break` keyword:

```
while (true) {
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    line = br.readLine();
    if (line == null) break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have an infinite loop which will keep on reading from the file and updating the screen. The content of the file *might* not even show on the screen because it would not seem that you are using the Event Dispatching Thread (EDT) to update the UI.

As a work around, consider using the [`WatchService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) which allows you to *watch* a directory for changes. Once that you notice a change in the file, you can read it and use the Event Dispatching Thread to update your UI (check `SwingUtilities.InvokeLater`).